# Find collision in Ajtai's hash function using short vector

Tags: lattice-crypto

### Background

**What is Ajtai's hash function?**

Given a matrix $A \hookleftarrow U(\mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m})$ and a column vector $\vec{m} \in \mathbb{Z}_d^m$, the hash of the message $\vec{m}$ is given by

$H(\vec{m}) = A\vec{m} \mod q$

**Ajtai's SIS-lattice**

The corresponding lattice for $A$ denoted by $L^{\bot}(A)$ is defined as all vectors $\vec{v}$ such that $A\vec{v}=\vec{0}$, in other words $L^{\bot}(A)$ is the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of $A$. Thus as far as I understand, to find a basis for $L^{\bot}(A)$ is essentially equal to [finding a basis for the kernel of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/finding-the-basis-of-a-null-space).

**The SIS-problem**

The $\beta$-SIS problem is the problem of finding a non-zero vector $\vec{v}$ such that $A\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ and $\|\vec{v}\|\le \beta$. This problem is known to be hard.

**Is the hash function collision resistant?**

Finding a collision for the hash function is as hard as solving the $2d\sqrt{m}$ SIS-problem. That means, given a collision $(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$ we can easily compute a short vector in $L^{\bot}(A)$ as $\vec{x}-\vec{y}$.

Why does it work? We have a collision, i.e $A\vec{x}=A\vec{y} \rightarrow A(\vec{x}-\vec{y})=\vec{0}$, so the vector $\vec{v}=\vec{x}-\vec{y}$ is in the lattice. Next, due to triangle inequality we have that $\|\vec{v}\| \le \|\vec{x}\|+\|\vec{y}\|$. Since both $\|x\|_{\infty} \le d$ and $\|y\|_{\infty} \le d$, it follows that $\|\vec{v}\| \le 2d\sqrt{m}$.

### Question

Now, my question is; is it possible to go the other way around? That is, is it possible to find a collision for Ajtai's hash function given a short non-zero vector found e.g using [Lentra-Lenstra-Lovász lattice reduction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm)?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you hit a problem? It would be cool if you‘ld edit you question accordingly. Don’t get me wrong, but we do expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking here – including searching this site for related Q&As that might shed light on your question. At worst it will help you frame *“[a better question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)”*; at best it might even answer it.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to come up with something that looks even close to a solution. What I've tried to do is solve the equation system with v=x-y and Ax=Ay but ending up with the zero vector. I also tried to combine the two shortest vectors in the LLL-reduced basis, but they don't hash to the same value (?) so it looks like a dead end to me. My lattice professor apparently thinks this is simple, I guess I've just overlooked something obvious. Hence the question.

Comment: Thanks for your edits – looks like a perfect question now! $(+1)$

Comment: I concur. I wish all questions were this nicely-written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the exact domain of the hash function and the quality of the SIS solution, i.e., its norm (and the choice of norm itself).

Suppose the hash domain is $\{-d, \ldots, d\}^m$, i.e., vectors of $\ell_\infty$ norm at most $d$. Then any nonzero vector in Ajtai's lattice having Euclidean norm at most $d$ collides with the all-zeros input. (Actually, $\ell_\infty$ norm at most $d$ suffices.) Thus, finding short enough lattice vectors yields collisions.

But now suppose $d=1$, say. (This is a typical choice.) For standard parameters, the shortest (in Euclidean norm) nonzero vectors in Ajtai's lattice have norm about $\sqrt{n \log q} \gg d = 1$.  Thus, short vectors in Euclidean norm (which is what typical lattice-basis reduction algorithms deliver) may *not* be sufficient to yield a collision.  Instead, finding a collision requires finding a shortest nonzero vector in the $\ell_\infty$ norm. But little is known about lattice-basis reduction algorithms for this setting.

More details on these issues can be found, e.g., in the paper "SWIFFT: A Modest Proposal for FFT Hashing" (I am a coauthor).