# domain of Ajtai hash function

Tags: lattice-crypto

I know that when the domain is  $\{0, 1\}^{m}$ in  function $h(x)=Ax$ for $A \stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}_{q}$, this function is called  Ajtai hash function. So when the domain is extended to $\mathbb{Z}_{q}^{m}$, is it also called Ajtai hash function?

[image]

Comment: When the domain is extended to $\mathbb{Z}_q^m$ it is no longer collision resistant, so one should be careful in what one means by "hash function".

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reminding.  I want to ask that if the domain is extended and at the same time the function is  collision resistant. Is the function with extended domain  also called Ajtai hash function?

Comment: I'm unaware of the particular name to use in this situation, but Peikert's answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34400/find-collision-in-ajtais-hash-function-using-short-vector?rq=1) makes that seem appropriate (provided the domain is suitably restricted).